# Does preallocating variables, used in member function, as member fields optimize performance? (C++)

Tags: c++, performance, class, optimization

Say I have defined a class

```
class myclass{
   private:
      /* some fields */
   public:
      void memberfun{
         int someint;
         double somedouble;
      }
}
```

My class has a member function, in which I need to declare a handful of variables. I need to call this member function many times (i need it for monte-carlo simulations). Since I will be simulating very large systems, I am interested in optimizing performance.

If I pre-allocate these needed variables as public member fields, such that I only need to access them and overwrite them, instead of allocating memory every time I call my member function and then deleting once I go out of scope, would this lead to a performance increase?

```
class myclass{
   private:
      /* some fields */
   public:
      int someint;
      double somedouble;
      void memberfun{
         someint = 1;
         somedouble = 2.0;
      }
}
```

Comment: My advice (and I've worked on Monte Carlo simulations), is to code in the most natural way, and then run your code through a performance profiler. If you're anything like me, you'll find bottlenecks in the most unlikely of places. Only use member variables if they are part of an object's state if you get my meaning. Don't use them as a variable trash-bin.

Comment: These are local stack variables of build-in types. No allocation is happening here. If these were more complex types, like `std::string` where allocation *might* happen, then you might need to worry about it. With local stack variables, it doesn't matter how many of them you have. The stack size is always the same size, regardless of whether you have 0 variables or a hundred of them.

Comment: The allocation of local built-in type variables (such as `int`, `double`, `char`, etc. or raw arrays of latter) are basically free. So preallocating as you suggested probably won't achieve any performance boost, but it will only make your source code less readable.

Comment: Aside from what was already told... Even if it were not about primitive types but containers which might be subject of significant allocations (worth to be re-used), why do you made them `public`? If they are for private use of a class instance / member function I would make them `private`. Protection is not about any perfomance impact (I know of), it's about compiler checks regarding allowing or denying access to them from a certain other part of code.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Regarding performance, as most people will tell you: the profiler is your answer, and this line of thinking is premature optimization.

But no doubt you'll find that local POD stack variables (which have 0 allocation overhead) will perform better than accessing member variables, which will be accessed through a `this` pointer.

Comment: I was thinking about this as well. The this pointer and the associated cache line might only be loaded when it is actually accessed not by invoking a member function. Stack variables have then a higher chance of being cached already. Overall this seems like an ultra optimization.

Comment: Overall this seems like it will make the program slower.